# Brother MFC-L2700DW printer does not work

Tags: printing

I have just purchased a Brother MFC-L2700DW and cannot seem to install it; it doesn't appear in the list of Brother Printers in Ubuntu 12.04. Does anyone know if this printer is actually supported?

Answer (score 13):

Ironically a friend of more than 20 years emailed me today with the same question about a similar model of Brother Printer, and I can vouch that he is using version 12.04LTS, because I'm the one who installed it for him.  I was able to save considerable typing by merely editing my reply to suit your model of Brother printer:

**Driver installation tutorial for Brother MFC-L2700DW**

1. Open [this link](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcl2700dw_us_eu_as).
   http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcl2700dw_us_eu_as
2. Be sure to check (DEB not RPM).  Ubuntu is Debian based, so downloading the RPM version will only lead to frustration.
3. With Linux and linux(deb) checked, press SEARCH.
4. The following page lists several choices, the first  one being the most comprehensive.
5. I recommend you download that first choice, the driver installer, and open it as soon as it has downloaded.  Doing so will open your Ubuntu Software Center and complete the software installation.

It should work immediately without rebooting, but in case of difficulty, reboot.

Comment: Are you saying my answer worked for you?

Comment: ahem... not to nag you to do me any favors, but ORDINARILY when someone likes one of my answers they click the little arrow over the 0 indicating approval so I get points for it.  Considering how many negative votes my rambley insightful commentary earns me on on this prickly site, I can use all the positive ones I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Download this files:

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf101791/mfcl2700dwlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf101792/mfcl2700dwcupswrapper-3.2.0-1.i386.deb

Install the drivers:

Turn on the printer and connect the usb, network or parallel cable.

Go to the directory where the drivers are.

In a terminal

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

run:

```
sudo -i

dpkg -i --force-all mfcl2700dwlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb

dpkg -i --force-all mfcl2700dwcupswrapper-3.2.0-1.i386.deb
```

Depending on the connection type you are using USB or Network, follow one of the steps below.

### For USB Connection:

```
Open a web browser and go to "http://localhost:631/printers".

Check if the Device URI of your printer is "usb://Brother/(your printer's model name)"

If the device URI is different from the example above, please go to "Modify Printer" of your printer to select proper device and driver.

If your printer is not listed on "http://localhost:631/printers", please go to "http://localhost:631/admin" and click "Add printer" and select proper device and driver.
```

### For Network Connection:

```
Open a web browser and go to "http://localhost:631/printers".

Click "Modify Printer" and set following parameters.

"LPD/LPR Host or Printer" or "AppSocket/HP JetDirect"       for Device

lpd://(Your printer's IP address)/binary_p1                 for Device URI

Brother                         for Make/Manufacturer Selection

Your printer's name             for Model/Driver Selection
```

### For Scanner driver 32bit:

Download this files:

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006646/brscan4-0.4.3-0.i386.deb

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006651/brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.i386.deb

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006654/brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb

Install the drivers:

Go to the directory where the drivers are.

In a terminal

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

run:

```
sudo -i

dpkg -i --force-all brscan4-0.4.3-0.i386.deb

dpkg -i --force-all brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.i386.deb

dpkg -i brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb
```

### For Scanner driver 64 bit:

Download this files:

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006645/brscan4-0.4.3-0.amd64.deb

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006652/brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb

http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006654/brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb

Install the drivers:

Go to the directory where the drivers are.

In a terminal

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

run:

```
sudo -i

dpkg -i --force-all brscan4-0.4.3-0.amd64.deb

dpkg -i --force-all brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.amd64.deb

dpkg -i brother-udev-rule-type1-1.0.0-1.all.deb
```

### For Network Connection to Scanner:

run:

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name=Brother model=MFCL2700DW ip=xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to recognize the printer

https://faithtechlife.com/2015/06/03/setting-up-brother-mfc-l2700dw-on-ubuntu/

I have tried xsane but somehow it could not find the printer.  I must have done something wrong.

But the printing job works fine