# MFC-L2700DW installation

Tags: printing

I recently tried to install a customer's Brother MFC-L2700DW without success. In the end, I tried to install another similar driver from ubuntu but know irt would't just let me go back top the original one. I am not that technical , but I thought it was worth giving it a try. I don't know whether you can point me to the right direction. Just tell me what commands to run and info to provide and I will do it.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install? What steps have you done?

Answer (score 0):

The printing part worked for me, i'm yet to try the scanning. It appears that you have to download the proprietary driver, a ".deb" file, directly from brother. 
[Brother MFC-L2700DW printer does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549840/brother-mfc-l2700dw-printer-does-not-work)