# Brother Scanner Error: Unable to connect to scanner

Tags: scanner, brother

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general and I would appreciate your help with the following:
When using my Brother MFC-L2700DW scanner with the Document Scanner software, the app finds the scanner through my WLAN, but I get the error "Failed to scan. Unable to connect to scanner".

I have installed all required drivers:

```
ii  brscan-skey                                0.3.1-1                               amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
ii  brscan4                                    0.4.9-1                               amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
ii  mfcl2700dwcupswrapper:i386                 3.2.0-1                               i386         Brother MFC-L2700DW CUPS wrapper driver
ii  mfcl2700dwlpr:i386                         3.2.0-1                               i386         Brother MFC-L2700DW LPR driver
ii  printer-driver-brlaser                     6-1build1                             amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                      1.4.2-3                               amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

I have also updated the *60-libsane1.rules* file with these additional lines:

`# Brother scanners ATTRS{idVendor}==”04f9″, ENV{libsane_matched}=”yes”`

And I further ran

`brsaneconfig4 -a name=MCF-L2700DW model=MFC-L2700DW ip=192.168.001.086`

Other suggestions that I found online for other Brother printers, such as running this here, also did not work:

`sudo apt purge ippusbxd`

I have further uninstalled and re-installed Document Scanner from the Ubuntu Software Center and did a number of reboots.

The printer function of MFC-L2700DW works fine, just not the scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Probably I'm a little bit late... I have had some hours before the same problem and was searching hours by hours.
In short form: May be the problem (and solution) is your IP-address 192.168.001.086, which your printer will get from your router
If you may ping this address, i.e.

```
ping 192.168.178.086 -w 10
```

and you will get something like "100% lost of packages", then have a kindly look on your router, which probably shows you the address of your Brother printer with ip = 192.168.001.86

Now try:

```
ping 192.168.178.86 -w 10
```

If successful, "edit"

```
/opt/brother/scanner/brscan4/brscan_gnetconfig
```

or to print brother model: DCP-1617NW

```
/opt/brother/scanner/brscan4/brsanenetdevice4.cfg
```

The easiest way is to double-click with your file-manager (as root) on this file. Then two IP-adresses will be shown. Choose the ...178.86 one. That's all. May be a reboot could be useful - or not...

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to the location of some of the installation files.

Oscar1919 ([Brother MFC-L2700DW printer can print, can't scan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970831/brother-mfc-l2700dw-printer-can-print-cant-scan)) indicated that some of the installation files may be copied into the wrong folder. For 64-bit Linux, the instructions were to check that the folder /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane exists. In my case, this folder was indeed present, but it was empty. The subsequent instructions were, essentially to copy the files libsane-brother* from the /usr/lib64/sane/ folder to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane. On my system, the three files to be copied were: libsane-brother2.so, libsane-brother2.so.1 and libsane-brother2.so.1.0.7.  Once these files were located in the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane folder, Simple Scan sprung to life and scanned a test document.

Comment: Thank you, I confirmed that the relevant files were already in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane. I have also followed the other suggested steps on the linked page (i.e. adding my username to the group that owns the scanner: `sudo adduser <myusername> lp`. It did however not solve my issue. Any other ideas?